# Why paypal sandbox amount does not changing after successfull transaction?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying since last 3 days and could not figure out why sandbox seller account does not updating the amount. However the transactions are showing into activity with `completed` status.

I tried to searched a lot on goolge but could not found the related thread.

Following is the response from Paypal after transaction process.

```
{
  "id": "PAYID-L**********8",
  "intent": "sale",
  "state": "approved",
  "cart": "2*******Y",
  "payer": {
    "payment_method": "paypal",
    "status": "VERIFIED",
    "payer_info": {
      "email": "business-buyer@xyz.net",
      "first_name": "test",
      "last_name": "buyer",
      "payer_id": "S**********4",
      "shipping_address": {
        "recipient_name": "test buyer",
        "line1": "Free Trade Zone",
        "city": "Dubai",
        "state": "",
        "postal_code": "971",
        "country_code": "AE"
      },
      "country_code": "AE"
    }
  },
  "transactions": [
    {
      "amount": {
        "total": "21.00",
        "currency": "USD",
        "details": {
          "subtotal": "17.50",
          "tax": "1.30",
          "shipping": "2.20"
        }
      },
      "payee": {
        "merchant_id": "K*******Q",
        "email": "business-facilitator@xyz.net"
      },
      "description": "Paying through paypal.",
      "invoice_number": "5*********2",
      "item_list": {
        "items": [
          {
            "name": "Project - Amount For Balance",
            "sku": "123123",
            "price": "7.50",
            "currency": "USD",
            "quantity": 1
          },
          {
            "name": "Project - Service Fee",
            "sku": "321321",
            "price": "2.00",
            "currency": "USD",
            "quantity": 5
          }
        ],
        "shipping_address": {
          "recipient_name": "test buyer",
          "line1": "Free Trade Zone",
          "city": "Dubai",
          "state": "",
          "postal_code": "971",
          "country_code": "AE"
        }
      },
      "related_resources": [
        {
          "sale": {
            "id": "8**********E",
            "state": "completed",
            "amount": {
              "total": "21.00",
              "currency": "USD",
              "details": {
                "subtotal": "17.50",
                "tax": "1.30",
                "shipping": "2.20"
              }
            },
            "payment_mode": "INSTANT_TRANSFER",
            "protection_eligibility": "ELIGIBLE",
            "protection_eligibility_type": "ITEM_NOT_RECEIVED_ELIGIBLE,UNAUTHORIZED_PAYMENT_ELIGIBLE",
            "transaction_fee": {
              "value": "1.01",
              "currency": "USD"
            },
            "parent_payment": "PAYID-L***********08",
            "create_time": "2019-04-14T11:37:37Z",
            "update_time": "2019-04-14T11:37:37Z",
            "links": [
              {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/8****4E",
                "rel": "self",
                "method": "GET"
              },
              {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/8VS3*******24E/refund",
                "rel": "refund",
                "method": "POST"
              },
              {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAYID-LSZ*******08",
                "rel": "parent_payment",
                "method": "GET"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "redirect_urls": {
    "return_url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/payment/execute-paypal-transaction?paymentId=PAYID-LS************08",
    "cancel_url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/payment/cancel"
  },
  "create_time": "2019-04-14T11:37:37Z",
  "update_time": "2019-04-14T11:37:31Z",
  "links": [
    {
      "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAYID-LS*************8",
      "rel": "self",
      "method": "GET"
    }
  ]
}
```

Can someone kindly guide me what can be the reason so that I can fix it. I would like to appreciate. Thank you so much.

Here is the paypal reference picture

[image]